# master-slave in dropwizard and hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, dropwizard, master-slave

I have an application written in Dropwizard and using hibernate to connect to DB(mysql). Due to new features being released, I am expecting high load for read apis and thinking of providing the reads from slave DB. What are the different ways in which i can configure master-slave and tradeoffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have solved:

1. I have 2 session factories in my case: one is default which talks to master and other one with a name say "slaveDb" which talk to slave database.
2. I have created different dao for same entity one for slave interactions and one for master. in slave dao i am binding it with the slaveSessionFactory
3. Now unit of work annotation has one attribute "value" if you don't use it , which we  do not in many cases then the annotation processor will talk on top of the default session factory. If you define a name over here then annotation processor will use the session factory with that particular name.

P.S. In my case I have a single slave as the application is not that high load and I wanted slave just for report generation purpose. In case of many slaves this solution doesn't scale well. Also As I was giving the slave machine details in my config.yaml file , I need not set the underlying connection as read only.

Comment: `Now unit of work annotation has one attribute "value"` - this was very useful

Comment: So, I see that I need to set the value attribute of the work annotation for the mapping between SlaveSessionFactory and the MasterSessionFActory right?
Is there any other global way of doing this for the whole application. My problem is that, I have a production application which is live for years, and there are no replication database set initially, we are trying to achieve it now. So, we are looking for a better solution with minimal number of code changes. 
I hope you would give your inputs.

Comment: cc ^^ @MartinKonecny

Comment: I dont believe there is a global way

Comment: I did some search again, but afraid that it's still not available. Let  me know how are you solving it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @UnitOfWork Annotation , then no and yes.
No, they donot directly allow you to communicate db using read only.
Yes, you can create two resources each using different  db (master slave).
One resource for writes and critically reads(master) another for read only(slave).

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/nxURxVWDtEY

Also as link suggest mysql driver can do this automatically, but for that session readOnly should be true which UnitOfWorkApplicationListener doesnot set properly  even if you set readOnly true in @UnitOfWork.